# Installing Python Package abc

Tags: python-2.7

I am trying to run someone's code and I hitting an issue with their imports

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod
```

I tried doing a `pip install abc` but that did not find any package named abc.

Has anyone used this package before?  If so, was `abc` the correct package name to install?  If not, what is the correct package name?  Using Python 2.7.13

Comment: you should that someone to give you that abc.py file too...!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to https://pypi.org/search/?q=abc

This queries all official registered python packages. It seems there a package abc which is orphened.

If someone else from your company or community wrote a package abc, there are two ways. Either yoy create a local repository and add abc there. or you install the package manually by creating a wheel file and install it with pip install

Answer (score 4):

For the record, I was able to search pypi and find a package that worked.  I installed abcplus `pip install abcplus` and that allowed me to execute the import statement.

Answer (score 0):

Here, most probably `abc` is a file in the same directory from which the packages ABC and abstractmethod are being imported.

Answer (score 0):

The import statement:

```
from abc import ABC
```

works only on python 3.

In python 2 you need to import ABCMeta and then inside the class do

```
__metaclass__ = ABCMeta
```

There are a couple of examples in the python documentation:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/abc.html